# Need an aggregation on datefield in elastic search which gets the count of a day of last six months (i.e. 1st of last six months count)

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Index in my elastic search which contains a date field "createdDate". Here, I need to get the count of documents with 1st date of last six months. i.e. I need to get the count of documents on 1st date for the period of last six months (e.g. count of 1st August, 1st July, 1st June, 1st May, 1st Apr, 1st May for september).

It would be a great help if someone looks into this and help.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Try date histogram aggregation.

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "monthly_cont" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "createdDate",
                "interval" : "month"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Refer [document here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html)

Comment: Here I get the count of complete month in a bucket. But I need to have individual day count in a single bucket. Here, 1st date bucket contains the sum of count of 1st dates of last six months.. @Shalin LK

Comment: If I put a day interval, it gives all the six months dates individual buckets. Here what I need is to sum all the months counts of same date. Can you please help in this matter. @Shalin LK

Comment: My result should be something like below:::     e.g.

suppose, let us assume the last 6 months as Jan-June. I need the result as below.

1st -- sum( count(1st Jan), count(1st Feb), count(1st Mar), count(1st Apr), count(1st May), count(1st Jun)),
2nd -- sum( count(2nd Jan), count(2nd Feb) , count(2nd Mar), count(2nd Apr), count(2nd May), count(2nd Jun)),
and so on.  @Shalin LK